# How to place rotated text properly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex wrapper with 3 columns, in third column there is rotated text, how can I place the text to the bottom right position of the column?

What I want:

[image: what I want]

What I have:

[image: what I have]

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column-2 {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also did you search if any one had the same issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5Drotate+text

Comment: https://codepen.io/romangulevskiy/pen/qBqBqge

Comment: You can create a snippet in your question from the `[<>]` button ;) A clear and easy question will help you .

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58038668/8620333

Answer (score 6):

[`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) can also be used to rotate text :

> The writing-mode CSS property sets whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically, as well as the direction in which blocks progress. When set for an entire document, it should be set on the root element (html element for HTML documents).

possible examples:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  border: solid;
  margin: 2em;
}


/* also */

.wrapper.bis {
  align-items: end;
}

.bis .column-2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper bis">
  <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

An older similar answer : [How do I center a transformed and rotated div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997506/how-do-i-center-a-transformed-and-rotated-div/37998794#37998794) *(when prefix was to be used )* applied here without prefix would do :

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform:scale(-1);
  border: solid;
  margin: 2em;
}


/* also */

.wrapper.bis {
  align-items: end;
}

.bis .column-2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper bis">
  <div class="column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

If you want to stick to transform, here is an older answer of mine that allows to stretch the container according to the string length : [How to display vertical text in table headers with auto height / without text overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997631/how-to-display-vertical-text-in-table-headers-with-auto-height-without-text-ov/22177247#22177247)

---

[`text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) can be usefull too :

> The text-orientation CSS property sets the orientation of the text characters in a line. It only affects text in vertical mode (when writing-mode is not horizontal-tb). It is useful for controlling the display of languages that use vertical script, and also for making vertical table headers.

Comment: you can add `transform: scale(-1);` to get the correct direction of the text

Comment: @TemaniAfif indeed , i gave up adding and explain it hopping that sideways-lr/sideways-rl will be part of the spec :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `display: flex` on the columns div, and adjust them as you need. I've made an example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/grazielle-carvalho/pen/RwowpQq)

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child first">Column 1</div>
  <div class="child second">Column 2</div>
  <div class="child third"><p>Column 3</p></div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.first {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.second {
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.third p {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.rotate {  
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: what about writing-mode to keep the text in the flow ?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper div {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.wrapper h3 {
  font-size: 0.4em;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 35px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
  <h1>Column 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Column 2</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Column 3</h3>
</div>
</div>
```